# Regex - avoid any unnecessary searches preg_match() PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hello i have small problem with my regular expression.

For simple:

```
$pattern='/^(a([0-9]|[a-z])?|b(\=|\?)?)$/';
$subject='b=';
```

returns array:

```
Array
(
[0] => b=
[1] => b=
[2] => 
[3] => =
)
```

Index number 2 in this array is from a(...)? - my question: can i avoid this field in my result? I have very long pattern and my array is in 90% empty. Can i remove this empty fields by some magic characters?

Edit:
In my pattern i have something like that:

```
n(o|h)?(\+|\-|\(([+]?[0-9]+);([+]?[0-9]+)\))?
```

It will search strings like no+ or n(12;15). Can i do it simpler? And i have more text like this, it means i have something like that:

```
/^(n(o|h)?(\+|\-|\(([+]?[0-9]+);([+]?[0-9]+)\))?|i(o|h)?(\+|\-|\(([+]?[0-9]+);([+]?[0-9]+)\))?)$/
```

Regards

Comment: Your pattern is probably badly designed. If you explain (with example strings) what you are trying to match we can suggest you a better approach.

Comment: Simplify it `^(?:a[0-9a-z]?|b[=?]?)$` like @CasimiretHippolyte pointed out

Comment: If you don't want to capture the content of brackets, use a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), i.e. instead of `(...)`, use `(?:...)`

Comment: I want this values but when i search n i want values to n, when i values to i, no values to n (where there all is null) and values to i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your pattern, I assume that you can make it simpler with this version:

```
\A([in][oh]?)([+-]|\(\+?[0-9]+;\+?[0-9]+\))\z
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO3mS5/3)

Note that i don't know exactly the captures you need, but you can add them as you want.

details:

```
\A                          # anchor for the start of the string
(                           # capture group 1:
    [in]                    # a 'i' or a 'n'
    [oh]?                   # a 'o' or a 'h' (optional)
)

(                           # capture group 2:
    [+-]                    # a '+' or a '-'
  |                         # OR
    \(\+?[0-9]+;\+?[0-9]+\)
)
\z                          # anchor for the end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks man, i can't give you +1 :< sorry bro and thanks again.